VMware Workstation Player 17.5.1 not compiling libs after install on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS desktop
After I had installed a clean Ubuntu 24.04 desktop version on my system (in place upgrade did not work), I had to install VMware Workstation Player 17.5.1 (current) again.
I know that there are WINE and VirtualBox, that does not help me right now. Every now and then I have to run some existing VM guests.
After I downloaded and installed the VMware Player successfully, I wanted to start it for the first time. It prompted me, that gcc (build-essential) tools were missing.
So I quickly ran sudo apt-get install build-essential, which installed me a fresh gcc 13.2.0-24ubuntu1.
Now VMware found the compiler but refused to build / make the libs and whatever stuff it needs, claiming that the 13.2.0-24ubuntu1 was not the identically same version that the 24.04 LTS kernel was compiled with, which seems to be gcc 13.2.0-23ubuntu4.
For two days I now tried several ways to get the older gcc installed properly (including installing and later removing gcc-12 etc.). Which I did obviously not succeed in.
Any one having similar issues and solution for it?

Same identical problem with VMware-Workstation-Full-17.5.2-23775571.x86_64.
This is the "free" version for non-professional use.
Help would be appreciated
thank you

The fact that no "drop in" libraries for Many new Linux releases (i.e. Ubuntu 24.04) for WS 17.5.2 has not appeared - yet (at the time of writing) - at https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules suggests that we have huge "Problem Child" here.
We are just going to have to be patient.
It may take some time as many of these new releases occurred at or around the time that v17.5.2 was released.
